# switch between different android repo tags

Tags: android, repository

I need to download src code of different android tags. Each time it takes half an hour and GIGS of space. Instead I'd prefer to switch to different tag. How can I do so?

```
cd android-4.0.4_r1.1
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.4_r1.1
repo sync


cd ../android-4.2.2_r1
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1
repo sync
```

What's the proper way to switch/update from android-4.0.4_r1.1 to android-4.2.2_r1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fetch tags with :

git fetch

git fetch --tags

And do checkout by :

git checkout tag_name

Also if it is taking more time to sync than usual run below command in that repo :

git gc

Comment: Also if all repos are using same branch to sync then you can simply change the default revision in manifest.xml to particular tag you want to sync..

Comment: I think my questions isn't about git, but about repo (a tool developed by google to manage android src). I know what I'm asking can be done with pure git, but I'm pretty sure that it's not going to be as simple as what you suggest. Are you sure that you understood my question?

Comment: " repo forall -c git checkout tag_name  "  is the command if you want to use repo. Repo is a tool which uses git commands internally.. you can run any git command using repo.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer, you can change the default revision in manifest.xml. There's a snippet about it in `repo help init`:

> ### Switching Manifest Branches
>
> To switch to another manifest branch, `repo init -b otherbranch` may be
>   used in an existing client. However, as this only updates the manifest,
>   a subsequent `repo sync` (or `repo sync -d`) is necessary to update the
>   working directory files.

This won't download everything fresh, but will perform the necessary git operations to checkout the correct branch/tag across projects. Actually, if you run it with `--trace`, you'll see it does a good bit more than just `git checkout`.

NOTE: If you use this method you must make sure you supply the exact same parameters to repo init as you had for your previous invocation. Specifically, if you supplied `-g` options, supply them again or `repo sync` will remove directories now unnecessary in the new set of groups.